# Do I really need high ST to use Telekinesis?

Tags: character-creation, psionics, gurps-4e

If I get the Telekinesis advantage, do I use my ST to move objects with it? I want to play a psionic character who is physically weak, but this wording makes me wonder if that's just not possible:

> You can move any object you have strength enough to lift, at a Move equal to your TK level…

That says I need my ST to lift the object, leaving me wondering if I used my TK level or my ST level for lifting things telekinetically.

If TK is not the right advantage to implement my character concept, have I missed the one that is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use your TK level in place of your ST when using TK at a distance. Right before that line that's tripping you up, the advantage explains this, albeit very quickly:

> You can manipulate distant objects just as if you were grasping them in a pair of hands with ST equal to your Telekinesis (TK) level.

So anywhere that Telekinesis refers to ST in relation to telekinesis, it's referring to a ST equivalent to your TK level, not your personal ST basic attribute.

There is one exception that TK provides though, letting you ‘boost’ objects when throwing them with your own hands — see the section *Throwing* at the bottom of the middle column on page 92. Otherwise, when using your own hands, use your own ST; when using Telekinesis, use your TK level where it says to substitute TK level for ST.